# How to implement Visual studio like docking in html5?

Tags: html, docking, panels

I am trying to implement the docking feature similar to that of the visual studio in **html5**.
After searching through the internet,there weren't much data I could get.

Are there any framework's or libraries or sample code to achieve this in html5?

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but having looked for something similar recently, check out http://www.dockspawn.com/. Also check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813511/docking-window-framework-written-in-javascript